# JavaFX get first day of next month

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

I'm trying to get the first day of the next month from a LocalDate object but have run into some issues.

I have a datepicker where a user can pick any date they want, without restriction and I need to get the next month's first day, this is what I've thought about doing:

```
LocalDate localDate = myDatePicker.getValue();
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.of(0, 0);

LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(localDate.getYear(), localDate.getMonthValue() + 1, 0);
```

However I see a problem that may occur when choosing the month December, if that happens then the call

```
LocalDate.of(localDate.getYear(), localDate.getMonthValue() + 1, 0);
```

Should fail because I'm passing it a month value of 13. Now I could choose to check if the month value is December and if so I could add 1 to the year and start at 0 like so:

```
if(localDate.getMonthValue() >= 12)
    LocalDate.of(localDate.getYear() + 1, 0, 0);
```

However I feel like there must be a way to get around this within the class itself. Does anyone know if my presumptions about passing 13 to LocalDate.of month value will cause an error? If so is there a way to do what I want to do that doesn't look so bad and uses a build in method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Custom way with :

   - `.plusMonths(1)`  to get the next month
   - `.withDayOfMonth(1)` to get the first day

     ```
     LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 15);
     LocalDate firstNext = localDate.plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
     // or     firstNext = localDate.withDayOfMonth(1).plusMonths(1);
     System.out.println(firstNext); //2019-01-01
     ```

---

2. Built-in way with :

   - `TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth()`

     ```
     firstNext = localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth());

     // does a temporal.with(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1).plus(1, MONTHS); operation
     ```

Comment: Note that this relies on the behavior of plusMonths truncating to the last day of the month when it "overshoots" (e.g. adding 1 month to January 30th). That *is* what it does, but I can imagine people reading the code wanting to check that. I find the `TemporalAdjusters` approach more "obviously correct".

Comment: @JonSkeet nnote sure to understand what you mean by "truncating to the last day of the month" ?

Comment: Depending on the API details, I could imagine "January 30th + 1 month" becoming February 28th/29th or March 1st, depending on the API designer. Both java.time and Noda Time take this "truncation" approach, but other APIs may do something different - it's not like there's one "obvious" right answer. The approach of "add a month and set the day to 1" doesn't work if the behaviour of "add one month" can go into the subsequent month. To be clear: the code works, but it's not *obvious* that it should work.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, most of what I've seen from things such as ZonedDateTime, LocalDateTime, LocalDate, Timestamp, etc... is that the API's seem overly complex for what they do

Comment: @Joe: I don't think I said that at all. And I would say that until you've tried designing a date/time API, you may well underestimate the required complexity to meet users needs - each individual user may only use 10% of what you provide, but a lot of people need different bits...

Answer (score 8):

Fortunately, Java makes this *really* easy with the idea of adjusters and [`TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#firstDayOfNextMonth()):

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 3);
        LocalDate date2 = date1.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth());
        System.out.println(date2); // 2019-01-01
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I chose to accept the other answer just due to the fact that future visitors could benefit from seeing both ways.

Answer (score 4):

Using `LocalDate` you can get `firstDayofNextMonth` with`TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth()`

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate firstDayOfNextMonth = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth());
        System.out.println(firstDayOfNextMonth);
    }
}
```